# Firefox web-console reference manual available?

Tags: firefox, console, firefox-developer-tools

In Firefox 46, I was looking for the `options` available for:

[image: screenshot --selector command]

The best I can get is [this page](http://meyerweb.com/eric/thoughts/2015/10/22/firefoxs-screenshot-command/).

I'm actually interested in the full reference of the Firefox console. The best incomplete reference I found is [this one](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Console). The `snapshot` command is not even mentioned.

Is there an official reference for the console?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's called the Developer Toolbar and the documentation is [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/GCLI).

To get help for any command type `help <command name>` and hit 'Enter'.

Here's what you get if you type `help screenshot`:

[image]

Comment: Type `help screenshot` and hit `Enter`. I've updated my answer above.

Comment: No need to specify the value `true`. Just add `--fullpage`. For example, `screenshot myfilename.png --fullpage`.

Comment: I see, thanks. You may want to include this in the answer as the problem is the inaccurate help file. However this doesn't solve my problem which is to save the hidden content of a scrollable panel. For instance I cannot use `screenshot myfile.png --selector #kc_widget_topic_TopicViewer_0` to save the right hand panel [here](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSB27U_6.3.0/com.ibm.zvm.v630.dmsa3/dtsispf.htm), even with `--fullpage` which is not helpful. Thanks anyway.